# When to change data attribute with "data" or "attr"?

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I am dynamically changing the data-attribute of a couple of elements. An 'img' and an 'a' type. The 'img' element works with the following code:

```
$("img[data-image-index-no-"+self.options.typeOfImage+"="+nextIndexNo+"]").data("image-index-no-"+self.options.typeOfImage, newIndexNo);
```

I then wanted to change an 'a' link element and wrote:

```
$("a[data-slide-index="+nextIndexNo+"]").data("slide-index", newIndexNo);
```

The above didn't work but the I got it to work using:

```
$("a[data-slide-index="+nextIndexNo+"]").attr("data-slide-index", newIndexNo);
```

I would like to know why using the `.data` works with the img element but not the 'a' element? And which method is the preferred way?

Any ideas on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Data vs Attr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

Comment: My first guess would be this - on `<img>` tag you already have `data-something` attribute added, while on `<a>` tag you don't? =) If `data-whatever` attribute isn't existent on an element, you need to create it first with `.attr()` and then modify it.

Comment: @Davion I do have the data-slide-index set on the 'a' elements. :-)

Comment: Then it has to be the function "firing" order. Like I wrote in my previous comment, `.data()` tries to find an existent `data-` attribute (the same moment when the specific method fires), while `.attr()` can change OR create that specific attribute if it can't find it. I'm guessing you're incrementing AND trying to find an element with new `nextIndexNo` before you update that same element.

Comment: @Davion I think you've hit the sharp point thing on the end! Thanks. Put that as an answer and I'll tick it up. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fire a `.data()` method it tries to find `data-` element's attribute. If the attribute is non existent, the method won't work.

Similarly to that, `.attr()` also tries to find some specified element's attribute with one difference that if it can't find it, it will **create** it.

So, in your case, I'd guess that you're incrementing **and** trying to find an element with new `nextIndexNo` before actually updating that same element. As that element has the old `nextIndexNo` value, `.data()` method won't be able to find it, thus why `.attr()` works.

Glad I could point you in the right direction =)